# Swarm node crashes when uploading big files

Tags: nodes, swarm

I noticed that when I try to upload files which size are around 100KB or higher to swarm, my node crashes with the following message:

```
panic: runtime error: slice bounds out of range

goroutine 27181 [running]:
github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/swarm/storage.(*LazyChunkReader).join.func1(0xc424b125b0, 0xc422322410, 0xc421ccd920, 0xc421ccdbc0, 0x0, 0xc42102afb8, 0xc42102afe0, 0xc420257000, 0x3000, 0x3000, ...)
    /build/ethereum-ZSPmrv/ethereum-1.7.3+build11486+xenial/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/swarm/storage/chunker.go:438 +0x3d9
created by github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/swarm/storage.(*LazyChunkReader).join
    /build/ethereum-ZSPmrv/ethereum-1.7.3+build11486+xenial/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/swarm/storage/chunker.go:437 +0x2bf
```

Has anyone experienced that too? Is there a way to patch this?

Edit: the directory where I'm trying to copy the file into, was mounted through swarmfs.